# Having problem Charging cards with Paystack js

Tags: api, payment-gateway, payment

I have been trying to integrate Paystack for a while and I got stuck in the card charging phase. After submitting the form,  my code returns and error that says readPin() is not defined. Paystack asked me to programmatically pass the pin provided by my customer and I don't even know what that is. What do they mean by the pin provided by customer? Will be glad if anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

what programming language are you using? What have you tried so far? It is best to provide a code sample and the exact response you get when you make the request.

(it's good practice to provide as much detail as possible when asking questions on StackOverflow.)

**However, what I suppose it means is that when you collect the PIN provided by the customer, you should make a POST request to https://api.paystack.co/charge/submit_pin with the collected PIN.**

Here is the API reference for that at https://developers.paystack.co/v1.0/reference#submit-pin.

You can also reach out directly to Paystack via your Paystack Dashboard > Get Help (on the bottom right corner) for quicker resolution.